How to export candidate data with specific paging size and increase page index count after every run?
How to export candidate data with specific paging size and increase page index count after every run? I am trying to schedule a process to export candidate data with a limited paging size of 300. But I want the page index to increase automatically after every run.
I don't see any option in the advance parameters

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
